# How to validation struct value is exist or not using for loop in C language

Tags: arrays, c, validation, struct

i want to ask you, here in my code i used case condition for input, but i got a trouble, in my code i want to check is my "NIM" value was inputted to struct or not, if it was inputted, it can't be inputted to struct. Here are my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct data {
    char nim[10];
};

struct data batas[100];
int a, b, c, d;
int i, j;
char x;

void inputdata()
{
  printf("\nInput Data\n");
  printf("=======================\n");
  printf("NIM : "); scanf("%s", batas[a].nim);
  for(i=0; i<a; i++){
    if (strcmp(batas[a].nim, batas[i].nim) == 0) {
      x = "FLAG";
    } else {
      x = "FLAGX";
    }
  }
  printf("%s", x);
  if (strcmp(x, "FLAGX") == 0) {
      a++; // This will input to struct
  }
}

void showdata()
{
  j=0;
  for(i=0; i<a; i++){
    j = j + 1;
    printf("\nData-%i", j);
    printf("\nNIM : %s", batas[i].nim);
  }
}

int main() {
  int menu;
  do {
    printf("\n\Choose input = "); scanf("%d", &menu);
    switch(menu)
    {
      case 1 : inputdata(); break;
      case 2 : showdata(); break;
    }
  }while (menu != 3);

  return 0;
}
```

From this i always get an error Segmentation Fault. I appreciate you guys, thank you.

Comment: First thing is to check out all the compiler warnings. Here's the first: `x = "FLAG";` but `char x` is the wrong type for this and the wrong type to pass to `strcmp`.

Comment: @WeatherVane i have tried to change the code to x[20], it still can't pass

Comment: I don't know what the code is supposed to do but if you change to `char *x` at least it compiles.

Comment: You must turn on warnings of your compiler. It will tell you a lot.

Comment: Even with `char x[20];` you cannot do `x = "FLAG";` but must do `strcpy(x, "FLAG");`

Comment: I think  from the looks of your program you are trying to check whether a string exist in your struct or not, is that correct, if so correct your program , explain what is `batas[a].nim` and `batas[i].nim`?

Comment: @IrAM Yes, that's correct.`batas[a].nim` is a value that will entered to struct. `batas[i].nim` is an array of struct

Comment: @PaulOgilvie thank you, i've already change `x = "FLAG";` to `strcpy(x, "FLAG");`, but now ini my code there is still strange in `if (strcmp(batas[a].nim, batas[i].nim) == 0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have already got many suggestion to check your program for warnings and errors.

Check warnings and errors of your program : https://onlinegdb.com/By1VeOK1d

```
main.c:20:9: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]   
                                                 
main.c:22:9: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]                                                    

main.c:25:12: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]    
                              
main.c:26:14: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strcmp’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]  
                             
/usr/include/string.h:144:12: note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘char’                                                       
main.c:44:12: warning: unknown escape sequence: '\C'
```

All of the above warnings will be cleared just by making two changes to your code

line 11 change `char x;` as `char* x;`
line 44 change `printf("\n\Choose input = ");` as `printf("\n Choose input = ");`

Moving on to your code correctness, your function `inputdata()` is depending on global variable `a` and the loop `for(i=0; i<a; i++){` is never true because `i < a` will never be true, since `a` is global (default value 0).

Which leads to execution of other statements in an undefined way.

you are directly reading your input into structure `scanf("%s", batas[a].nim);`, instead read into a local variable like `char temp[30]` , then add it your `batas` and continue checking for the existence of your string from next input.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct data {
    char nim[10];
};

struct data batas[100];
int a, b, c, d;
int i, j, flag;

void inputdata()
{
    flag = 0;
  printf("\nInput Data\n");
  printf("=======================\n");
  printf("NIM : "); 
  scanf("%s", batas[a].nim);
  for(i=0; i<a; i++){
    if (strcmp(batas[a].nim, batas[i].nim) == 0) {
      flag = 1;
    }
  }
  if (flag == 0) {
      a++; // This will input to struct
  }
}

void showdata()
{
  j=0;
  for(i=0; i<a; i++){
    j = j + 1;
    printf("\nData-%i", j);
    printf("\nNIM : %s", batas[i].nim);
  }
}



int main()
{
    int menu;
  do {
    printf("\n\Choose input = "); scanf("%d", &menu);
    switch(menu)
    {
      case 1 : inputdata(); break;
      case 2 : showdata(); break;
    }
  }while (menu != 3);

  return 0;
}
```